# Zooming into specific div with Zoomooz

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zooming

I have a seatmap that looks a bit small on mobile and currently requires a pinch option to zoom into on mobile.

i was introduced to Zoomooz which looks great, but struggling to get it working on nested divs. Is it possible to zoom into the specific area you require to view a seatplan in more detail?

https://plnkr.co/edit/9VL3mDS34bKAe7qRxHYE?p=preview

```html
<div id="theatre">
<div class="container">
  <div id="bmessage">Select the seats that you need.</div>
  <div id="seats" class="zoomTarget">
    <div class="s1 std grey" si="0" title="A16" style="top:16%; left:8.5%;"></div>
    <div class="s1 std grey" si="1" title="A15" style="top:16%; left:12%;"></div>
    <div class="s1 std grey" si="2" title="A14" style="top:16%; left:15.5%;"></div>
    <div class="s1 std grey" si="3" title="A13" style="top:16%; left:19%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the cdn link of the `Index.html` and apply `ZoomTarget` to each `div` on which you want to apply zoom functionality
 Check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bHeobBIGUgPzmFukOxC5?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zoomooz/1.1.6/jquery.zoomooz.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="theatre" class="zoomViewport">
  <div class="zoomContainer container">
        <div id="bmessage">Select the seats that you need.</div>
        <div id="seats">
        <div data-closeclick="true" class="zoomTarget s1 std grey" si="0" title="A16" style="top:16%; left:8.5%;"></div>       
        <div data-closeclick="true" class="zoomTarget s1 std grey" si="1" title="A15" style="top:16%; left:12%;"></div>
        <div data-closeclick="true" class="zoomTarget s1 std grey" si="2" title="A14" style="top:16%; left:15.5%;"></div>       
        <div data-closeclick="true" class="zoomTarget s1 std grey" si="3" title="A13" style="20px;top:16%; left:19%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```